# I am trying to identify whether a shape in excel has a connector attached to it from within VBA. Can it be done?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

So I'm trying to identify, within VBA, whether circle shapes in my sheet have connectors attached to it (and ideally check how many connectors).

However, All I can find when searching for solutions online is that you can do the inverse - i.e. check if connectors have shapes at their beginnings and end.

I need to do it the other way around. Is it possible, and if so how?

Comment: If you know how to go from connectors to shapes then you can loop over all connectors and see if any of them are linked to your shape of interest...

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Private Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, shp, shpSearch As Shape
    Dim colFrom As New Collection, colTo As New Collection
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set shpSearch = ws.Shapes("Rectangle 3")
    
    SetConnectors ws, shpSearch, colFrom, colTo
    
    Debug.Print "Connectors from shape: " & shpSearch.Name
    For Each shp In colFrom
        Debug.Print , shp.Name
    Next shp
    
    Debug.Print "Connectors to shape: " & shpSearch.Name
    For Each shp In colTo
        Debug.Print , shp.Name
    Next shp
 
    
End Sub

'Given a worksheet and a shape, populate the two collections with any
'  shapes on that sheet which connect to the provided shape
'  ByRef is default, but added here for clarity
Sub SetConnectors(ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, _
                  ByRef colFrom As Collection, ByRef colTo As Collection)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        If sh.Connector Then
            With sh.ConnectorFormat
                If .BeginConnected Then
                    If .BeginConnectedShape Is shp Then colFrom.Add sh
                End If
                If .EndConnected Then
                    If .EndConnectedShape Is shp Then colTo.Add sh
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Tested with no grouped shapes and seems to be fine.  If you have grouped shapes you may need to make adjustments.